# Installing a plain plugin jar in Eclipse 3.5

Tags: eclipse

Since Eclipse 3.5 there seems to be no option to have drop a plugin jar ( not a feature ) in the Eclipse base directory and have it picked up at next startup.

Is there any possiblity to have plain plugins jars installed in Eclipse 3.5?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Since the advent of p2, you should be using the [dropins directory](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_p2_Getting_Started#Dropins) instead.

> To be completely clear create "plugins" under "/dropins"
>   and make sure to restart eclipse with the "-clean" option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That did not work since the dropins folder expects a properly formatted jar _with metadata_, which I don't have.

Comment: That's inaccurate. At most, put it in the dropins in a folder which is named plugins.

Comment: To be completely clear create "plugins" under "<eclipse_root>/dropins" and make sure to restart eclipse with the "-clean" option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just put my plugin jar file in the dropins folder and it worked 

Answer (score 15):

Simplest way - just put in the Eclipse plugins folder. You can start Eclipse with the -clean option to make sure Eclipse cleans its' plugins cache and sees the new plugin.

In general, it is far more recommended to install plugins using proper update sites.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That does not work anymore in Eclipse 3.5 . Any I'm aware of the proper way of installing plugins, just that it's not available for a plugin I'm using.

Comment: @ulkas did you find a way to solve this problem ? I also using Eclipse Luna.

Comment: @Kami im sorry i dont remember anymore whether yes or no, but now im using v4.5 (mars) so probably not

Comment: @ulkas thx the solution above worked after several times of trying :) Thx for your answer...

Answer (score 14):

For Eclipse Mars (I've just verified that) you to do this (assuming that C:\eclipseMarsEE is root folder of your Eclipse):

1. Add **plugins** folder to C:\eclipseMarsEE\dropins so that it looks like:
   C:\eclipseMarsEE\dropins\plugins
2. Then add plugin you want to install into that folder:
   C:\eclipseMarsEE\dropins\plugins\someplugin.jar
3. Start Eclipse with clean option.
4. If you are using shortcut on desktop then just right click on Eclipse
   icon > Properties and in Target
       field add: -clean like this: C:\eclipseMarsEE\eclipse.exe **-clean**

[image]

5. Start Eclipse and verify that your plugin works.
6. Remove **-clean** option from Target field.

Answer (score 6):

go to `Help` -> `Install New Software...` -> `Add` -> `Archive...`. Done.

Comment: Not for me. Always tells me that it cannot find the folder I choose. How can I find out where the plugins folder is? This is not a standard installation, so telling me where it normally is doesn't help. I am no admin on this computer, so I cannot reinstall anything, but adding plugins works when I add a remote repository. This particular plugin is only available as a .jar file.

Comment: Nope, this will only work for `.zip` files that include `contents.jar` within the archive.

Comment: And you cannot just rename the `.jar` file to `contents.jar` and put it inside a `.zip` file, right? Didn't work for me at least.

Answer (score 2):

in Eclipse 4.4.1

1. copy jar in "C:\eclipse\plugins"
2. edit file "C:\eclipse\configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info"
3. add jar info.
   example:
   `com.soft4soft.resort.jdt,2.4.4,file:plugins\com.soft4soft.resort.jdt_2.4.4.jar,4,false`
4. restart Eclipse.

Comment: Hello, I feel like I am very close to getting my plugin to work. What do I do for the first two parameters of that statement if I do not have an online repo where my plugin gets updates from? All I have is the .jar so I do not know what to put for the "com.soft4soft.resort.jdt" Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can go about it:

1. Close Eclipse
2. Download a jar plugin (let's assume its testNG.jar)
3. Copy testNG.jar to a certain folder (say C:\Project\resources\plugins)
4. In your Eclipse installation folder, there is a folder named dropins (could be C:\eclipse\dropins), create a .link file in that folder, (like plugins.link)
5. Open this file with any text editor and enter this one line:
                   *path=C:/Project/resources/plugins*
6. Save the file and start Eclipse.

And you are good to go!


**Please do not forget to change your backward slashes in your plugins folder path to forward slashes on step 5. I used to forget and it would take my time unnecessarily.**