# How to install .jar files into Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have written a Eclipse plugin project and successful export the .jar files. But after i copyed .jar files into the Plugins folder (tried also the dropins folder)and restarted the Eclipse, i still can't find the plugin in the "Eclipse Installation Details".

After i install a plugin from Eclipse Marketplace(Any One), i can find my plugin in the "Eclipse Installation Details".Does anyone know why?

Comment: Did you use the "Export wizard" available in the MANIFEST.MF editor (overview tab) to generate the jar files ?

Comment: Copy the jar into to the dropins directory, and not the plugins directory. The 'plugins' directory is for plugins installed using the update manager.

Comment: I have provided an answer here on [how to add a jar plugin to Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61910828/4560682)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you export your plug-in - presumedly via the Plug-in Export Wizard - have a look at the export option (first page) "Install into host repository". Using this you can update the p2 director directly from the wizard.