# Installing Apache Felix Webconsole

Tags: eclipse, apache-felix

Trying to install the Felix Webconsole to help with OSGi development using 
the tutorial here: http://industrial-tsi-wim.blogspot.com/2012/12/running-apache-felix-webconsole-from.html

1. Downloaded the org.apache.felix.webconsole-4.2.0.jar and placed it in my /dropins directory.
2. Installed Apache Commons IO (version 1.4.0), Apache Commons FileUpload and JSON Implementation for Java through the Install New Software menu.
3. Started jetty through the console.
4. Use console command "ss webconsole", the console returns an empty list.

I also tried the three solutions given at [Installing a plain plugin jar in Eclipse 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926594/installing-a-plain-plugin-jar-in-eclipse-3-5) since it looked like a similar problem.

Putting the .jar in a "plugins" folder in dropins does nothing, as does putting it in the plugins directory.

Trying to install through Help > Install New Software... > Add.. > Archive and selecting the downloaded .jar, gives the error **"No software site found at *file location*"**

I can install the .jar using "install *download URL*". This installs the bundle and let's me start it, but I'd like a way to have it install locally, and start automatically, or in a more "push button" way than having to mess with the console.

After getting webconsole manually installed and started, when I try navigating to "localhost:8888/services/console" (Jetty is configured to use port 8888) I get a 404 page saying
 **"Problem accessing /service/console. Reason: ProxyServlet: /service/console"**

Comment: The following article may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19521622/installing-and-running-web-management-console-in-apache-felix-osgi/30467214#30467214

Regards

Comment: Alternatively you could give https://github.com/evandor/skysail-webconsole a try, it should start up without any problems (at least that is the idea ;) - it is still in early alpha).