# How to install a bison/flex syntax highlighter?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, syntax-highlighting, eclipse-cdt, bison, flex-lexer

for my flex and bison files  I am looking for a syntax highlighter.

I am trying to get this to run: http://ccode.tistory.com/77 :

1. I downloaded the .jar file
2. and followed the instructions File/import [Adding jars to a Eclipse PlugIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5744520/adding-jars-to-a-eclipse-plugin)

But nothing changed.

Can somebody explain to me how to install it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the instructions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/926949/141719) to install the jar file.

After doing this and restarting eclipse, .y files should be opened with the Bison editor provided by the plugin, and syntax-highlighted.